# Multiple time and day input (web)

Tags: web-app, input-fields, datetimepicker

I am currently working on a web app that requires the HR of a company to input the reporting days and time of all the employees into the system.

The system requires the following information:

1. Work days for the company collectively
2. Reporting timings for each day

**Example scenarios:**

1. Scenario A

   1. Mon-Thu: 7.00AM, 10:00AM, 5:00PM
   2. Fri-Sun: 9:00
2. Scenario B

   1. Mon-Fri: 8:00 AM

My current solution is as such (Drew inspiration from one of Google's settings page):

1. User selects work days
2. Time row appears based on selected days
3. Input reporting timings for each day
4. If most reporting times are the same everyday (E.g. Scenario 2), user can 'Copy time to all days'

[image]

We have done usability testing for the design and it is generally working fine but can be a little time consuming especially when we need the user to input both reporting and ending times...

Wondering if anyone here has other solutions or feedback on this?

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm wondering...
Is the time frame (eg 07:00-10:00) more important than the length of the session (3 hours)?

I've prepared another concept of time tracking, in which the user's task is to report how long an action took, as opposed to when it was.

[image]